# Laravel Select records in specific year

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1

I'm new to Laravel and struggling to identify how I can select all records created in 2015 using the created_at field provided by the timestamp.

The model I am using is Blog:

```
$posts = Blog::latest()->get();
```

Example date in database:

```
2015-01-25 12:53:27
```

Could anyone shed some light?

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can  do it like that:
`$posts = Blog::where( DB::raw('YEAR(created_at)'), '=', '2015' )->get();`

Here you can get year from created_at field with YEAR function, then compare with your date.

Comment: i think using local-scopes https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#local-scopes or DB::whereYear(...) like post above (https://stackoverflow.com/a/46259677/3557623) is even better the using DB:raw() because it's not compatible to all databases.

Answer (score 34):

Just for completition. There is a Laravel method for it.

```
Blog::whereYear('created_at', 2017)->get();
```

See [where clause](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries#where-clauses), subsection `whereDate / whereMonth / whereDay / whereYear`

Answer (score 2):

You can use scope function in your model.
Eg:

Your Model

```
class Blog extends Eloquent {
    public function scopePopular($query,$year)
    {
        return $query->where('year', '=', $year);
    }
}
```

Usage

```
$blog = Blog::popular(1999)-get();
```

Answer (score 1):

Scope Function Worked perfectly for me:

```
class Blog extends Eloquent {
public function scopeSeason($query,$year)
{
    return $query->whereYear('created_at', '=', $year);
}
```

}

Usage:

```
$blog = Blog::where('status','active')->season(2021)->get();
```